# Is there a relationship between "levels of measurement" and groups/rings/fields?

Tags: group-theory, measurement-theory

Stevens's classification of scale provides "levels of measurement" which imply how values in a dataset may be understood/manipulated:

| level | mode | median | mean | ⊕ | ⊗ | zero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nominal/categorical | × |  |  |  |  |  |
| ordinal | × | × |  |  |  |  |
| interval/cardinal | × | × | × | × |  |  |
| ratio | × | × | × | × | × | × |

where ⊗ is the addition operation and ⊗ is the multiplication operation.

Is there a formal relationship between these levels of measurement and groups/rings/fields?

There doesn't seem to be a level for partial orderings (assuming "ordinal" refers to a total ordering) or non-commutative multiplication.

One of the reasons I'm interested in this is that some data I'm dealing with comes as real-valued scalar, vector, or tensor values; but sometimes the context implies that, for instance, they are nominal, ordinal, or interval measurements rather than ratio measurements. Since I cannot assume the level of measurement from the structure implied by the underlying group from which measurements are drawn, what information is best conveyed with the data to constrain how it can be analyzed/visualized?

Answer (score 0):

Nominal / categorical means your measurements just form a set $X$ with no additional structure. Ordinal means $X$ has a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) as you say.

I don't quite understand what "interval / cardinal" means, but a minimal algebraic structure that lets you define means is the structure of a [convex space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convex+space), which lets you take [convex linear combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination). This is a weakening of the concept of an [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) where you can take affine linear combinations. Notably this does *not* let you define the sum, which is not a convex or affine linear combination; for example the set $[0, 1]$ of probabilities is a convex space and it is not probabilistically meaningful to add two probabilities which sum to greater than $1$. So I don't agree with the third row that the ability to take means is necessarily paired with the ability to add.

I really don't understand what "ratio" means but it sounds like it implies that $X$ is a ring, probably even a commutative [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) since you are supposed to still have the ability to take medians. In mathematics it's clear that the concept of having an order and having addition or multiplication operations are logically independent; $X$ could have an order but no addition or multiplication, or it could have an addition or multiplication but no order. And the order could be partial or total and the multiplication could be non-commutative, at least in principle.

> One of the reasons I'm interested in this is that some data I'm dealing with comes as real-valued scalar, vector, or tensor values; but sometimes the context implies that, for instance, they are nominal, ordinal, or interval measurements rather than ratio measurements.

I don't understand what this means; can you be more specific?

Comment: While these classifications are from statistics, they do not apply to probabilities but rather events that probabilities measure.

Interval/cardinal indicates that differences between values may be compared to one another. Consider a sports team: each member's jersey number is nominal. Even though integers provide addition and subtraction, the differences between these numbers do not convey meaning. However, the height of a player may be relevant to the sport and so differences between the heights of players may be compared (making it interval/cardinal).

Comment: Ratio indicates that division of one value by another is meaningful. The canonical example here is temperature: ratios of Celsius and Fahrenheit values are not meaningful because their zero value, while physically significant (at least Celsius), allows negative values. The Kelvin or Rankine scales do not admit negative values. Similarly, pressure may not be negative. As best I can tell, "ratio" indicates that ratios will always be unsigned and meaningful for comparing values.

Comment: As far as my particular application, Stevens's classifications are useful as far as they go but I also run into data where other factors matter (e.g., commutivity). I'm hoping there is some formalism that can separate the mathematical structure of the distributions from which the data is drawn and the physical context so I can annotate the data to constrain what visualizations are meaningful and relevant and what ones are not.

Comment: As you point out, the Stevens' classification of scales seems incomplete in several aspects. However, I haven't come across anything more rigorous that can take physical context into consideration.